No value passed for parameter 'thirdNumber'
How can I fix this error?
fun main() {
    println(add(10,7,9))
}

// Define add() function below this line
fun add(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int, thirdNumber: Int): String {
    val result = add(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    val anotherResult = add(firstNumber, thirdNumber)
   
    return "$firstNumber + $secondNumber = $result"
    return "$firstNumber + $thirdNumber = $anotherResult" 
}


There are several problems with your code:

you can't return two things from a method
the recursive call to add with 2 arguments is not possible as your method requires 3 arguments. Kotlin allows optional arguments however, so you can make the third argument optional (Int? = null) or initialize it with a default (Int = 0)
you're not actually adding the three arguments, only building the sum of first+second and first+third.

Here's a version with optional second and third arguments that works:
fun main() {
    println(add(10, 7, 9))
    println(add(8, 15))
    println(add(42))
}

fun add(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int? = null, thirdNumber: Int? = null): String {
    val items = listOfNotNull(firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber)
    return "${items.joinToString(" + ")} = ${items.sum()}"
}

Output:
10 + 7 + 9 = 26
8 + 15 = 23
42 = 42

Or even more elegant with vararg:
fun add(vararg numbers: Int): String {
    return "${numbers.joinToString(" + ")} = ${numbers.sum()}"
}


The problem is that you defined a function add with three parameters and in that function you want to call another function, also named add, but with just two paramters. There is no built-in function with that name, so the only function that would be available is the function itself (that would be allowed, it's called recursion), but that needs a third paremter which you don't provide. That's the reason for the error message: The only add function available needs three paramters.
You can create an additional add function with just two parameters, though:
fun add(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int): Int {
    return firstNumber + secondNumber
}

Now your code would work.

I'm not quite sure about what you want to achieve but one option could be:
fun add(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int, thirdNumber: Int): String {
  val result = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber
  return "$firstNumber + $secondNumber + $thirdNumber = $result" 
}

